# Custom Sorting Function In JQuery Datatable like "anti-the"

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I want to Create Custom sort function for Jquery Datatable like

> anti-the

I have a column where student's full name is there with their honorifics like for eg. `Mr. Fname Mname Lname`.

While Sorting It should ignore the first Mr.|Mrs.|Ms. and Should Sort according to Remaining data in Fname

I tried this, but its not working

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "anti-the-pre": function(a) {
    return a.replace(/^mrs\.|^mr\.|^ms\. /i, "");
  },
  "anti-the-asc": function(a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
  },
  "anti-the-desc": function(a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: '/DataService.asmx/getData',
  method: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    var t = $('#studentDataTable').DataTable({
        data: data,
        "columnDefs": [{
          type: 'anti-the',
          targets: 0
        }],
      }
    });
});
```

> Here is the [Jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/t31f14fp/).
>   Anyone knows how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a leading blank after replacement. You end up sorting on `' Hardik Vinod Thaker'` not `'Hardik Vinod Thaker'` so

```js
return a.replace(/^mrs\.|^mr\.|^ms\. /i, "").trim();
```

A regex-guy would probably include the blank as word boundary `\b`. But you are not obligated to use a custom sort, you can do it all in the `render` function you already is using  :

```js
render: function(data,type,row) {
   var concatName = data['fname']+' '+data['mname']+' '+data['lname']
   return type == 'sort' 
      ? concatName.replace(/^mrs\.|^mr\.|^ms\. /i, "").trim()
      : concatName
}
```

When dataTables wants the value of a column for sorting, then pass the concatenated name without honorifics. Demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/hn8v9hqx/**

Comment: Opps..! thank You so much Sir..and thanks for the Explanation :)